Collect[f[a x + b y + c x], x] does not work. How to collect terms inside a function?
How to collect terms inside a function such as Collect[f[a x + b y + c x], x]  or in the index such as Collect[Subscript[f, a x + b y + c x], x]?

If there are more than one such collection to perform in an expression, then expr /. p_ /; PolynomialQ[p, x] :> Collect[p, x].

You can use Map:
Collect[#, x] & /@ f[a x + b y + c x]
(* f[(a + c) x + b y] *)

Collect[#, x] & /@ Subscript[f, a x + b y + c x]
(* Subscript[f, (a + c) x + b y] *)

If your expression has more levels, you should map over all levels:
Map[Collect[#, x] &, f[a x + b y + c x, g[d x + e x, f x + g x]], All]
(* f[(a + c) x + b y, g[(d + e) x, (f + g) x]] *)


And just for illustration, you can always use /. with pattern  like this
expr = f[a  x + b  y + c  x]
expr /. f[any_] :> f[Collect[any, x]]


expr = Subscript[f, a  x + b  y + c  x]
expr /. Subscript[f, any_] :> Subscript[f, Collect[any, x]]


There are probably 8 other ways to do this Mathematica ;)

Using ReplaceRepeated:
f[a  x + b  y + c  x] //. a_.  x + b_.  x :> (a + b)  x


f[(a + c) x + b y]

f[a  x + b  y + c  x, g[d  x + e  x, f  x + g  x]] //. a_.  x + b_.  x :> (a + b)  x


f[(a + c) x + b y, g[(d + e) x, (f + g) x]]

Subscript[f, a  x + b  y + c  x + d  x] //. a_.  x + b_.  x :> (a + b)  x


Subscript[f, (a + c + d) x + b y]

Or using ReplaceAll and PolynomialQ:
f[a  x + b  y + c  x, g[d  x + e  x, f  x + g  x]] /. 
p_ /; PolynomialQ[p, x] :> Collect[p, x]


f[(a + c) x + b y, g[(d + e) x, (f + g) x]]


f[a x + b y + c x] // Query[{1 -> (Collect[#, x] &)}]

(* f[(a + c) x + b y] *)

and
Query[{1 -> (Collect[#, x] &)}] // Normal

(* MapAt[Collect[#1, x] &, 1] *)

